# Chain Spec json vs. Genesis json

Tags: private-blockchain, genesis

I keep reading about chain spec json files and genesis .json files.  I'm in the last stages of firing up a private network with a unique chain spec, and I wonder if I *also* need a genesis.json?  Or does the "genesis" section of the chain spec cover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The genesis section of the Parity chain spec file covers it.  However if the chain spec differs significantly from Geth defaults, the network will not be usable by Geth as Geth is not as configurable as Parity.

Answer (score 2):

`Chain Spec json` is for parity and `genesis.jcon` is for Go Ethereum

#### Translate Geth to Parity Ethereum chain spec. [keorn/parity-spec](https://github.com/keorn/parity-spec)

Comment: If I already have a chainspec file, do you know how to turn it into a genesis file?

Comment: @stone.212 see my edit